# xamarin.forms add switch in toolbar

Tags: xamarin.forms, switch-statement, toolbar, uiswitch

Is it possible to add a switch on the toolbar?

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem>
        <Switch x:Name="Switch1" IsToggled="True" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </ToolbarItem>    
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleViewSample"
             x:Class="TitleViewSample.MainPage">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
             <Switch x:Name="Switch1" IsToggled="True" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>    
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out.

Comment: What is NavigationPage coming from? Do you mean contentpage?

Comment: When you create an application without setting the main page as a navigation page(                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageName());
), you couldn't get navigation bar. If you have an initialized navigation page you could get the navigation bar and you can custom it.

Comment: Ok, I will check this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. You can, however, take the same approach I did when I needed to customise my title bar.

First, you hide the navigation bar, then you can specify your bar at the top, and use the controls you would like.

Comment: That would be awesome. Can you please make a code sample of how that is possible?